# I am using DevExpress Toolkit,and i dont know how to set unbound expression dynamically?

Tags: devexpress

Let me tell you in detail, I am using devexpress toolkit,
I know how to set unbound expression properties from designer,
but my task is that, i have one column, name Formula in my database table,
in that column i already insert some formulas like (qty*rate) for amount field.
now i have to set this formula dynamically when i run my form.

e.g qty | rate | amount

```
 10 | 10   | 100
```

so when i enter qty and rate,amount should b calculated by that formula.
i hope you understand what is my problem.
I am looking forward to your reply.
Thank You.

Comment: Do you have different formulae in each record of the Formula column in you table?

Comment: yes it can be a different,for various columns such as for amount i told,
if there is column of discount then it also have a different formula.

Comment: What platform are you using? WinForms, ASP.NET, etc.

Comment: Winform, Devexpress tool kit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unbound columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477). Add as many unbound columns as you have in your table and set the [GridColumn.UnboundExpression](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_UnboundExpressiontopic) property to a column formula.

If you may have different formulae in cells of a single column, handle the [CustomUnboundColumnData](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) event and calculate a cell value based on a formula. To calculate it, you can use ExpressionEvaluator. See https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T132971 for how to use it.

Comment: Hiii
Thanks for your reply.
I know how to set unbound expression from designer,but that is not my requirement,
if i set it from designer it would be fixed like static,
user cant change it later on,
So i entered formula in database and wann get it from database.
Hope you understand what i am trying to say.

Thank you

Comment: You can set this property in code. You don't need to do this in designer only.

Comment: But as i told you already, i want to set it from database.
And even i am able to set also,
but not performing..:(

Comment: Are you filling a DataTable or executing an SQL query directly? Can you update your question to illustrate this?

Comment: yes i m filling data table,and i m getting my value in data table also,but at last its not performing on my gridview

Comment: Can you get a value from the field with your formula of a particular row and pass it to the UnboundExpression property?